# JScrollPane not appearing on a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I searched on stackoverflow & on the internet, but it did not work. The scroll bar does not appear. Please, help me, I will be happy to vote for your answer if it works. Here is the code:   (Thanks in advance!)

```
package com.james.client;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class Main extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String [] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
{
    //Set program to nimbus
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
     }
    }
    //Window stuff
    JFrame window = new JFrame("MinecraftProgrammer++");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(1000, 600);
    window.setResizable(false);

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(null);

    JMenuBar nav = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu newfile = new JMenu("New");
    JMenuItem Class = new JMenuItem("Class");
    JMenuItem Package = new JMenuItem("Package");
    JMenuItem Other = new JMenuItem("Other");

    newfile.add(Class);
    newfile.add(Package);
    newfile.add(Other);
    file.add(newfile);
    nav.add(file);

    JTextPane code = new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane codescroll = new JScrollPane(code);
    codescroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    codescroll.setBounds(0, 0, 994, 547);
    code.setAutoscrolls(true);
    code.setBounds(0, 0, 994, 547);

    content.add(codescroll);
    content.add(code);
    window.setJMenuBar(nav);
    //No more code after this line
    window.add(content);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
content.add(code);
```

You've already added the JTextPane to the ScrollPane. You don't need to add the JTextPane again to your JPanel.

Comment: @JamesL. No problem. Made this error plenty of times myself when starting out with Swing.